# React Countdown Reset

Tags: javascript, reactjs, settimeout, use-effect

I'm trying to build a countdown timer but I'm facing an issue which I don't understand.
When I press start the timer works fine and the same goes when I pause it.

The problem is when i press the reset button, which is supposed to stop the countdown and reset it to its original value(at the moment 25).

When I press it the countdown stops, it goes to 25 but then it goes to the previous number. For instance if I press it at 16, it stops, goes to 25 and then back at 16 or 15.

I guess it has something to do with `useEffect` since `handleReset` updates both `counter` and `runnning` but I'm not really sure why.
If anyone could explain to me the reason that would be great.

Here's App.js

```
const App = () => {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(25);
  const [running, setRunning] = useState(false);

  const handlePlayPause = () => {
    running ? setRunning(false) : setRunning(true);
  };

  const handleReset = () => {
    setRunning(false);
    setCounter(25);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (running) {
      counter > 0 && setTimeout(() => setCounter(counter - 1), 1000);
    }
  }, [counter, running]);

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <h1>Pomodoro Timer</h1>
      <div className="set-timer">
        <Break />
        <Session />
      </div>
      <Display counter={counter} />
      <Controller handlePlayPause={handlePlayPause} handleReset={handleReset} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

And the full code here:
https://codepen.io/mugg84/pen/yLepaKm?editors=0010

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `setTimeout(() => setCounter(counter - 1), 1000);` cause a problem. you need to stop `setTimeout` before you reset the counter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few things here I'd probably change.

First off, `handleReset` shouldn't probably set `running` to `false` as the counter is still running. You only reset the value.

Then, to fix the issues I'd suggest using `setInterval` and you need to use `clearInterval` in combination with `useRef`. The logic can be simplified, but this is more readable I guess.

```
const handleReset = () => {
    // stop on reset
    clearInterval(timer.current) 
    timer.current = undefined;
    
    setCounter(25);
  };

const timer = React.useRef(undefined);
  

React.useEffect(() => {
    if (running) {
      if (!timer.current) {
        timer.current = setInterval(() => setCounter(prevCounter => prevCounter - 1), 1000);
      } else if(counter == 0 && timer.current) {
        // stop if reached 0
        clearInterval(timer.current) 
        timer.current = undefined;
      }
    } else {
      // stop if turned off
      clearInterval(timer.current)
      timer.current = undefined;
    }
  }, [counter, running]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the below changes. Issue is due to counter setting state after 1 second, by this time running is already set to false and hence when counnter is updated after 1 second, it becomes to old value. So, we can set it to null and handle that case explicitly.Below code is working as you described

```
const App = () => {
  const [counter, setCounter] = React.useState(25);
  const [running, setRunning] = React.useState(false);

  const handlePlayPause = () => {
    running ? setRunning(false) : setRunning(true);
  };

  const handleReset = () => {
    setRunning(null);
    setCounter(25);
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (running) {
      counter > 0 && setTimeout(() => setCounter(counter - 1), 1000);
    }
    else if(running == null){
      setCounter(25);
    }
  }, [counter, running]);

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <h1>Pomodoro Timer</h1>
      <div className="set-timer">
        <Break />
        <Session />
      </div>
      <Display counter={counter} />
      <Controller handleReset={handleReset} handlePlayPause={handlePlayPause}/>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't using `clearTimeout` and that was causing the issue.

I've updated `useEffect` and it's working like a charm.

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (running && counter > 0) {
      const timer = setTimeout(() => setCounter(counter - 1), 1000);
      return () => clearTimeout(timer);
    }
  }, [counter, running]);
```